# Import data from one google analytics account to another

Tags: google-analytics

I have multiple websites on my Google Analytics account, I accidentally added "Website1" analytics code to "Website 2".
I just noticed this after 3 months of logs.
Website 2 has no data logged, and the first website has all the second website data.

1- Can I import the second website data from Website 1 to Website 2 account.

2- Can I filter the data in Website 1 account to filter all data coming with the second website domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1, no. 
There is an API to export data, however this will allow you to export aggregated data only. You cannot get at the raw hits. Even if you could, there would be no way to import them (you cannot create hits via data imports, and you cannot resend hits that happened in the past since you cannot set a date on a request that sends data to GA).

As 2, partly yes.
You cannot permanently remove historical data from Google Analytics. However you can use a [segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en) to hide it in the data that is already collected, and you can set a [view filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en) (in the view settings of the admin section) to prevent new hits from the wrong domain to be collected. Both the segment and the filter would work on the hostname field (by either excluding the wrong domain, or specifically only including the correct domain).